# Crashed when putting button on tableview cell, unrecognized selector

Tags: swift, uibutton, uitableview

> PatientTableViewCell viewBtn:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x7fdde280ac00
>
> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   NSException

Any ideas? Thanks

```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let current_patient = patients[indexPath.row]
    let cell = myTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("patientCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PatientTableViewCell
    let type = current_patient.enrollable_type
    var unique_id = current_patient.unique_id
    cell.patientTypelbl.text = type
    cell.patientIDlbl.text = unique_id
    cell.viewBtn.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.viewBtn.addTarget(self, action: "viewDetailAction:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    return cell
}

   @IBAction func viewDetailAction(sender: UIButton){
    print("clicked")
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("patientDetailCell", sender: self)
}
```

for patientTableviewcell:

```
 class PatientTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var viewBtn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var titleType: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var titleID: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var patientTypelbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var patientIDlbl: UILabel!
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

}

Comment: If you are using Swift 2.2, you should use the more explicit `#selector(viewDetailAction)` instead of the string `"viewDetailAction:"`.

Comment: The error message says that the class `PatientTableViewCell` has no method or function `viewBtn`

Comment: @vadian I have post the code for patientTableviewcell. Should i put the button action code to patientTableviewcell?

Comment: Yes just add the action here for the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake was to set an IBAction from the xCode editor, and programmatically add a selector target to the same button..

First of all remove your `IBAction` setting from **Referencing Outlets** like here in the picture:

[image]

After that you must rename your function by removing IBAction tag:

```
func viewDetailAction() {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually what @kennytm says is true but it's only a warning for the moment but in the end you will need to use the syntax : `action : #selector(YourViewController.yourFunctionName)` . 
Your issue is that you add to your `viewBtn` a target of `viewDetailAction` but this must be a function and not an Action from the Storyboard.

You can just declare this function :

```
func viewDetailAction() {
    print("clicked")
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("patientDetailCell", sender: self)
}
```

and delete your action :

```
 @IBAction func viewDetailAction(sender: UIButton){
    print("clicked")
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("patientDetailCell", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: You should maybe set the action for the button directly in your PatientTableViewCellController from the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

you have two options here

1. comment the following line in your cell for row index path and check the button action is there or not.
   cell.viewBtn.addTarget(self, action: "viewDetailAction:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
2. use what you have mentioned code and rename the button action method name
   "@IBAction"